# python3 get all .dart files from given directory

Tags: python-3.x, path, glob

I would like to get **all**. `.dart`-files from a specific path.

This is what I've got so far:

```
import glob
import pathlib
       
libPathString = str(pathlib.Path.cwd().parent.resolve()) 

for path in glob.glob(libPathString + "/*.dart", recursive=True):
    print(path)
```

Now this is already giving me all the `.dart` files in the `libPathString` - directories. But inside there Ive got a couple of folders that have `.dart` files and these sub-directories can also have subfolders and so on.

I set `recursive = true` but that doesn't seem to achieve going through the sub-directories.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working! This is working as expected:

```
import glob
import pathlib
       
libPathString = str(pathlib.Path.cwd().parent.resolve()) 

for path in glob.glob(libPathString + "/**", recursive=True):
    if(".dart" in path):
        print(path)
```